# Can't install passenger 3 on Snow Leopard (with RVM and ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard, passenger, rvm

I've been trying to install passenger with no success yet.

I've installed the gem, but when I run

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

it tells me

```
This installer must be able to write to the following directory:
/Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.0
But it can't do that, because you're running the installer as myname.
Please re-run this installer as root.
```

but if I do

```
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I get

```
/Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:762:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem passenger (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
```

from /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:219:in `activate'
 from /Users/myname/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1065:in`gem'
 from /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:18:in `'

I've tried to look at those files, but cannot understand what's wrong.

can you please help?

thanks, P

Comment: what right has your directory /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/ ?

Comment: I assume the second command you ran was "sudo passenger-install-apache2-module," not "passenger-install-apache2-module" again, right?

Comment: Shingara: drwxr-xr-x // bnaul: you're right. corrected :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually chmod the folder as Shingara suggested and it worked.

the only thing I can't understand is why issuing the command with sudo lead to problems :(

thanks for your help!

Comment: Because you're not supposed to use sudo when running anything that involves RVM. Always use rvmsudo instead.

Answer (score 32):

Two solutions:

1. Use rvmsudo, not sudo.
2. Fix your directory permissions. /Users/myname/.rvm should be writable for myname but for some reason you caused that not to be the case.

Comment: rvmsudo worked for me also having the exact same error trying to get passenger-install-nginx-module working thanks for this!

Comment: Wow, rvmsudo, they have thought of everything!

Comment: I just ran into this same problem and rvmsudo made it work for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use system ruby instead of RVM ruby for installing passenger:

```
rvm use default
sudo gem install passenger
sudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```