# Error when installing Phusion Passenger "Could not find passenger (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, passenger, cpanel

I'm following [these directions](http://blog.davejamesmiller.com/2011/12/installing-rails-3-1-ruby-1-9-on-a-cpanel-11-30-server#comment-43034) to install Rails 3 on my WHM/cPanel VPS. The only change I'm making is to use Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.3

However when I get to the command to run "passenger-install-apache2-module" I'm having issues.

First, due to PATH issues I need to go into the correct directory to run the command.

More importantly, once I execute the command I get the error "Could not find passenger (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)" (Full error below).

The square brackets are empty, so I verified that the gems were there via "gem list --local" and passenger is listed.

System Specs:

CENTOS 5.8, WHM 11.32, VPS with root access

Full error:

```
/home/tekruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find passenger (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/tekruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /home/tekruby/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /home/tekruby/ruby/gems/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This worked for me, I used rvmsudo, not sudo.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4167707/cant-install-passenger-3-on-snow-leopard-with-rvm-and-ruby-1-9-2

Comment: @Thanos Please accept [the champion answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11107949/535406) (hit the check mark on his left).

Answer (score 22):

You are doing it inside a rails app path, try:

```
cd ..
```

and then

```
passenger-install-apache2-module
```

I guess it works

Comment: this worked for me, but would love an explanation why.

Answer (score 12):

I just went through this, you can try:

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurred because of the path issues.

if you are using rvm then please use the following commands to fix it.

rvm list(This will show all the list of ruby version you have in your system)

then

rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194(Whichever version you want it).

I hope this might help you to solve the problems

cheers
Shan

Comment: `rvm list` only showed one version of Ruby installed. I gave the `rvm use ...` command and am still getting the same error.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
sudo  apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```